# What is the maximum number of nodes I can traverse in an undirected graph visiting each node exactly once?

Tags: graph, tree, nodes, traversal, graph-traversal

So I have an un-directed un-weighted graph. It *contains* cycles. I would like to *find the path which visits the most nodes with no repeat visits to any node*. Since this is a graph traversal, you can start and end at any node you like.

**Background Research:**
I have looked at Travelling Salesman Problem (TSP); this problem is different and does NOT allow you to finish where you started from and there are no weights. I have looked at several other algorithms, but have found none suitable for this problem.

**Graph Size:** There are 100 nodes in the graph; with 10 disconnected nodes.

**UPDATE:** I have moved this to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243375/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-nodes-i-can-traverse-in-an-undirected-graph-visiti

Comment: Might be a better fit at [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graph-theory).

Comment: @Chirayu Shishodiya I am stuck in this problem since many days. If you have got the solution then please tell me. It will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

Look for the Hamiltonian Cycle problem

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_cycle

Comment: This is not a Hamiltonian path problem. The graph MAY have a Hamiltonian path but it is not definite.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem) which has an algorithm for acyclic graphs. Your graph has cycles which makes your problem NP-hard.

I would try and create a DAG with nodes representing strongly connected components. Then you could at least find the path that visits the most strongly connected components. You could then expand that path by replacing the individual (strongly connected components) nodes with the longest paths in each of the subgraphs.

Finding the longest paths in the subgraphs is now the same as your original problem but at least you graphs are smaller. If your in luck, the subproblems are easy and your done. In the general case they might not be so small and you could use some advanced heuristics. Maybe have a look at [this paper](http://www.combinatorialmath.ca/G&G/articles/longpath.pdf) or [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679081/how-do-find-the-longest-path-in-a-cyclic-graph-between-two-nodes) (you could use the answer there to solve your problem completely but i'm not sure)